# Entity Framework Map Nested entites to View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

Here are my view models. The entities are exactly the same structure except the name has no ViewModel

```
public class CelulaViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int? CheckListId { get; set; }
    public CheckList CheckList { get; set; }
}

public class CheckListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }        
    public IList<CheckListGrupoViewModel> Grupos { get; set; }

    public IList<CelulaViewModel> Celulas { get; set; }
}

public class CheckListGrupoViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public IList<CheckListGrupoItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CheckListGrupoItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my page Model

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

        public IndexModel(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        #region Properties    
        public CelulaViewModel Celula { get; set; }


        #endregion

        #region Handlers
        public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Celula = _context.Celulas
                .Include(c => c.CheckList)
                .ThenInclude(cl => cl.Grupos)
                .ThenInclude(cl => cl.Items)
                .Where(c => c.Automated)
                .Select(c => new CelulaViewModel
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Nome = c.Nome,
                    CheckListId = c.CheckListId,
                    CheckList = new CheckListViewModel
                    {
                        Id = c.CheckList.Id,
                        Nome = c.CheckList.Nome,
                        Grupos = new List<CheckListGrupoViewModel>
                        {
                           // ?? How to map the list in here?
                        }
                    }
                })
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (Celula == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(string[] id)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("../Index");
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

As you can see i'm trying to map the enty and sub entities to the view model and sub view models. The problem is when trying to do it with ICollections. I have no idea how to deal with this in lambda expression

Comment: Can I provide you an approach using AutoMapper ?

Comment: yes I used automapper before but not with this many nested lists

Comment: Just update my answer with complex include like your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I'm using automapper to map complex data

```
var vm = new IndexViewModel
{
  Posts = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<PostListViewModel>>(posts)
}
```

Below is the related entites. I have Post and PostListViewModel

```
public class Post : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public PostStatus PostStatus { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual Media Medias { get; set; }
}

public class PostListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public PostStatus PostStatus { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Media Medias { get; set; }
}
```

And the profile

```
public class PostProfile : Profile
{
    public PostProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Post, PostViewModel>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Another sample (complex one)

```
public class CommentProfile : Profile
    {
        public CommentProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Comment, CommentDto>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
        }
    }

    public class Comment : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public virtual User? User { get; set; }
        public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommentDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid UniqeId { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
        public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is how I map all data

```
    var comments = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Comment>().Query()
                .Include(x => x.User)
                .Include(c => c.Post)
                .Select(x => new CommentViewModel
                {
                    User = _mapper.Map<User, UserViewModel>(x.User),
                    Post = _mapper.Map<Post, PostViewModel>(x.Post),
                    Comment = _mapper.Map<Comment, CommentDto>(x),
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: These times we should care about the client evaluation of the query execution. It bothered me some times. But your models seems OK.